# react net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when try to GET data from backend node on localhost

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nginx, axios

I have a frontend `react` that uses `axios` to get data from a separate `node` server. The frontend uses a `.app` domain with SSL certificate but the backend `http://localhost:3001`, vanilla http, IP address, and port.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

...

```
axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:3001/',
        params: {page: pageNumber, limit: limit},
        cancelToken: new axios.CancelToken(c => cancel = c)
    }).then( res => {
        setSermons( prevSermons => {
            return [...new Set([...prevSermons, ...res.data.map( sermon => sermon )])]
    })
        setHasMore(res.data.length > 0)
        setLoading(false)
    }).catch( e => {
        if (axios.isCancel(e)) return
        setError(true)
    })
    return () => cancel()
}, [query, pageNumber, limit] )
```

... and here is my backend node/express server:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const knex = require('knex')
require('dotenv').config()

const db = knex({client: 'pg', connection: <...connection stuff...>})
const app = express()
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let page = req.query.page || 0
    let limit = req.query.limit || 50
    db.select('*')
        .from('sermons')
        .limit(limit, {skipBinding: true})
        .offset(limit*page)
        .then( (data) => {
            res.json(data)
        })
        .catch( (err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
})

const port = process.env.APP_PORT   
app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}, http://localhost:${port}`));
```

I can open both the frontend and backend parts of the site on my browser. The backend is accessible via http://157.xxx.xxx.xxx:3001 IP and the frontend maps to my domain. But the frontend can't retrieve data from the backend.

All of this is running behind an `nginx` reverse proxy. I did not find any firewalls installed on the server. Yesterday it was working but overnight the connection refused error started. I know that previously, I left the localhost out of the nginx setup entirely.

It seems like CORS is not working, even though the node server is importing/using it. What more can I look at to debug this?

Comment: Afterwards, I tested pulling content from this `node` server in the cloud to my local copy of the frontend server, using the public IP address, and it worked. So there's something specifically on my server that is blocking the `react` frontend server from talking to the localhost backend server that was not there yesterday (When it last worked).

Answer (score 0):

try adding `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"` to your package.json

it will proxy your backend and resolve CORS issues. You can read more about it in this blog post:

https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/react-how-to-proxy-to-backend-server-5588a9e0347

Comment: I tried that. IT didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

it does sound like a Cors problem
here is a quick video explaining on how cors works

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4KHiSt0oLJ0&ab_channel=Fireship

try adding a proxy in the package.json or set a header like this

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

Comment: I've tried the "proxy" in `package.json` and I've tried adding this header to the node server already, after the `db.select()...` statement. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I couldn't get the backend server to work with http://localhost:3000 but it did work if I mapped it to a true external API with https. This is the final configuration that worked:

`nginx.conf` file for JUST the backend server. Previously it was absent from `nginx.conf` because I was trying to make it a localhost only endpoint.

```
    server {
        listen 443 ssl; # using port 3000 wont work on some wifi, so incoming is 443 (ssl)
        # server_name 157.xxx.xxx.xxx; # gets blocked because mixed content http / https

        server_name <app.mydomain.com>;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<app.mydomain.com>/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<app.mydomain.com>/privkey.pem;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;       #<--- react-backend server listens on this port
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
    }
```

How the frontend react app uses `axios` to talk to backend. The backend endpoint is now HTTPS, with a separate, valid SSL certificate for that the `<api.mydomain.com>` subdomain:

```
axios({
       method: 'GET',
       mode: 'cors',
       url: 'https://api.<mydomain.com>',
       params: {page: pageNumber, limit: limit}, // { q: query, page: pageNumber },
```

changes to my `node/express` backend server endpoint

```
const express = require('express')
const knex = require('knex')
require('dotenv').config()
const cors = require('cors')
var corsOptions = {
   origin: '*',
   optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions))

const db = knex({...config stuff})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    db.select(... --> ...res.data)
    res.setHeader('Acess-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
})
const port = process.env.APP_PORT
app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}, http://localhost:${port}`));
```

I think many of these changes were not needed, but this is a working state, over https.

Next I'll see if I can block access to this backend to everyone except the frontend domain.